# Picking selected items from stdin via choices typed into console

Tags: bash, filter

Can anyone point me at a 'pick' filter script that works somewhat as described below?

I've spent about an hour hunting for a simple bash script/filter that will allow me to pipe in a list of values and will spit out a subset of them depending on choices I make at the console. I know there are examples written in C but I wanted a mostly-portable bash script I can use in Cygwin / Gitbash etc.  (The context: I want to be able to run some command in some subdirectories, and I want to separate the choice of which directories to run the command, from the choice of command to run.)

As hypothetical example of usage:

```
$ echo "foo
> bar
> baz" | pick.sh
* Options:
* 1. foo
* 2. bar
* 3. baz
* Choices? 2 3 
bar
baz
```

The lines marked * are supposed to be where the script interactively lets me choose which elements to 'pick' and once I decided lines 2 and 3 it proceeds to send those out to STDOUT.

Choices ideally could be a combination of space-separated numbers eg 2 3 4, inclusive ranges eg 2-4 .. or maybe even fancy enough to use some kind of autocompletion allowing typing the first few letters of the items themselves.

Well, there it is, I think it would be a very useful bash pipeline filter in general!

(Thanks for reading this far..)

Comment: The right tool: [`vipe`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125586/108618).

Comment: @Kamil I'd upvote this elegant general solution if I could. Do you know if it's easy to install in GitBash?

Comment: I have no experience with GitBash at all. Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: I just copied the vipe script from joeyh's git repo and stuck it in my bin folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self-demonstrating example using `sed` line specifiers (where `N,M` means lines N through M):

```
$ ./pick.sh < ./pick.sh
Lines:
     1  #!/usr/bin/env bash
     2  
     3  set -o errexit -o nounset -o noclobber
     4  
     5  trap 'rm --force --recursive "$working_directory"' EXIT
     6  working_directory="$(mktemp --directory)"
     7  input_file="${working_directory}/input.txt"
     8  
     9  cat > "$input_file"
    10  
    11  echo 'Lines:'
    12  cat --number "$input_file"
    13  
    14  IFS=' ' read -p 'Choices: ' input < /dev/tty
    15  lines=($input)
    16  
    17  sed --quiet "$(printf '%sp;' "${lines[@]}")" "$input_file"
Choices: 1 5,7 17
#!/usr/bin/env bash
trap 'rm --force --recursive "$working_directory"' EXIT
working_directory="$(mktemp --directory)"
input_file="${working_directory}/input.txt"
sed --quiet "$(printf '%sp;' "${lines[@]}")" "$input_file"
```

Basically, save standard input to a temporary file, print the file with line numbers, prompt for input ranges, and pass the input ranges to `sed` to print each of them.

One quirk of this method is that lines will be printed in the order they appear in the file, not the order you specify:

```
…
Choices: 3 1
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -o errexit -o nounset -o noclobber
```

If you really need input order it would be simple to loop over `lines`, although this is of course less efficient.

The script assumes you have *GNU* `cat`, `sed`, etc. installed. If you're using BSD tools the command flags will be different.

Comment: Cheers @l0b0 (greetings to Absolutely Positively Wellington btw), I'm guessing use of  comma as range separator is here driven by bash's array access syntax (been away from bash for about a decade..) so it should be straightfwd to also accept hyphens too.

Comment: Nothing to do with Bash, it's `sed` that expects ranges to be comma separated. For example, `sed --quiet 1,3p` will print the first three lines of standard input. You could do a `sed 's/-/,/g'` to preprocess `$input` before creating the array to support hyphens.

Comment: Thanks, I took a closer look, and adapted the sed args with ```sed 's/,/ /g;s/-/,/g;s/ p/p/g'``` to allow comma-separating single line numbers in the input, and hypen-separating ranges.. which feels more natural when typing in my choices. (Last clause not necessary just tidies out some spaces in sed command.)

Comment: Discovered minor problem when `pick.sh` called in backticks within another script like:  

`    for d in \`cat subdirs.txt | pick.sh\`
do
    pushd $d
    # process commands in selected dir e.g. mvn clean
    popd
done`


The list of choices was not seen in the terminal (presumably going into output stream) till I appended `1>/dev/tty` to your echo/cat commands (lines 11-12).

Comment: Sorry I ran out of 'edit time' on prev comment trying to get the excerpt to render correctly.. I've tried three backticks as code fences, I've tried <code> tags and <pre> tags, nothing seems to work in comments sorry!

Comment: That's a separate issue, so it should be a separate question. But it looks like you need a `while read` loop.